# Convert columns with multiple rows of data to rows with multiple columns, removing duplicate reference numbers

Tags: excel, vba

I have a data set similar to the below:

[Example data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsYoa.png)

I would like to convert the data to multiple columns where duplicate ID's (column 1) are removed and all other data is consolidated into single rows split across columns.

I have tried the following code from another thread:

[Convert columns with multiple rows of data to rows with multiple columns in Excel.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12613507/convert-columns-with-multiple-rows-of-data-to-rows-with-multiple-columns-in-exce)

However this results in column two data also being consolidated across columns where there are duplicates in rows.

For example, the above table would appear as

[Current result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLij6.png)

I need to amend the code so that it only removes duplicated data in column 1 and spreads the remaining data across columns.

I would like the data to end as follows:

[Desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NtJ1.png)

Below is the code i'm using:

---

```
Sub ConsolidateRows_SpreadAcross()

Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long, j As Long
Dim colMatch As Variant, colConcat As Variant

application.ScreenUpdating = False 'disable ScreenUpdating to avoid screen flashes

lastRow = range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'get last row

For i = lastRow To 2 Step -1

    If Cells(i, 2) = Cells(i - 1, 2) Then
        range(Cells(i, 3), Cells(i, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Copy Cells(i - 1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 1)
        Rows(i).Delete
    Else
        If Cells(i, 1) = Cells(i - 1, 1) Then
            range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Copy _
                Cells(i - 1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 1)
            Rows(i).Delete
        End If
    End If

Next

application.ScreenUpdating = True 'reenable ScreenUpdating

End Sub
```

---

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

With your data in its current pattern you do not need to check both column A and column B.

```
Sub ConsolidateRows_SpreadAcross()

    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim colMatch As Variant, colConcat As Variant

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'disable ScreenUpdating to avoid screen flashes

    With Worksheets("sheet15")

        For i = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1

            If .Cells(i, 1) = Cells(i - 1, 1) Then
                .Range(.Cells(i, 3), .Cells(i, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Copy _
                  Destination:=.Cells(i - 1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1)
                .Rows(i).Delete
            End If

        Next i

        .Cells(1, "C").Resize(1, .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Columns.Count - 2) = "data"

    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True 'reenable ScreenUpdating

End Sub
```